# Generation of sequential serial number based on prefix value

Tags: excel, vba

We have prefix defined already (say ABC, GIJ, THK, JLK ...so on) and want to create a sequential number when a user wants to generate a number for each of these prefix like given below:

ABC0000 , ABC0001 , ABC0002 ...ABC9999 same for GIJ0000 , GIJ0001 , GIJ0002 ...GIJ9999.

Given below is the code written for the above logic, but it does not achieve the requirement:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With ComboBox1.Value

Dim a, b As String

Dim i, j, k, l, x, q, m, temp As Long

a = ComboBox1.Text

i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, Range("A1:A1000"), 0)

j = Cells(i, 2)

l = j * 1000

For q = 2 To 100

For m = 2 To 100

If Cells(q, m).Value < 0 Then

k = m

End If

Next

Next

x = l

If Cells(i, GC).Value = temp Then

click = click + 1

Else

click = 0

End If*

Cells(i, GC) = x + click

TextBox1.Text = x + click

temp = Cells(i, GC).Value

End With

GC = GC + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you using k for? The whole for loop are useless

Comment: BTW, when defining variable as in `Dim a, b As String`, `As String` only applies to b, not to a. If you want a to be a String, you need to repeat `Dim a As String, b As String`. Same for the Long on the next line.

Comment: How does the "user generate a number"? button click? Your code would be easier to understand if you assigned meaningful variable names

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not seem necessary for this. Assuming you have your prefixes in separate cells in ColumnA starting in Row1, put in B1:

```
=A1&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)-1,"0000")
```

and double-click its fill handle.

[image: SO33256452 example]

Comment: sir, this code is not working properly,if there is possible try to send full code .....for this will thankful to you

Comment: what we are getting is that the sequence is generating numbers irrespective of prefix like given below - ABC0000 , ABC0001 , ABC0002 ,GIJ0003 , GIJ0004 , GIJ0005 rather it should be GIJ0000 , GIJ0001 , GIJ0002

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I assume that you have a ComboBox named ComboBox1, a CommandButton named CommandButton1 and a TextBox named TextBox1, all on a UserForm, and with ComboBox1 filled with the possible values for prefixes.

The following code will put the next available code(1) for the selected prefix into the TextBox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim a As String
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        a = ComboBox1.Text
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a & "9999", Range("A1:A1000"), 1)
        j = CLng(Mid$(Cells(i, 1).Value, Len(a) + 1)) + 1
        TextBox1.Text = a & Format(j, "0000")
End Sub
```

Your code is also doing a lot of unnecessary stuff.

(1) only if data is sorted.